# Select rows with nearest datetimes from input set of datetimes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with thousands of rows and I am only interested in a handful of them with datetimes closest to a set of input datetimes.

Is there a more performant way to execute this query?

```sql
(select * from table1
where datetime >=
to_timestamp('2015-12-31 14:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
limit 1)
union all
(select * from table1
where datetime >=
to_timestamp('2015-12-31 20:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
limit 1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/160b34/13

Comment: Please explain what are your trying to do, and why do you need/want to avoid the UNION ALL.

Comment: A query with `LIMIT` and without an `order by` makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to do here? Get the two rows that are "closest" to those two timestamp values? And what's wrong with your UNION ALL approach?

Comment: @Bestter Updated question to reflect that I am looking for a more performant way to run this query if one exists. Thanks

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the table in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a simple explain). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the logic using a lateral join (in Postgres 9.3+):

```
select v.ts, t1.*
from (values (to_timestamp('2015-12-31 14:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')),
             (to_timestamp('2015-12-31 20:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
     ) v(ts) cross join lateral
     (select t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t1.datetime >= v.ts
      order by v.ts asc
      limit 1
     ) t1;
```

I think this will have reasonable performance with an index on `table1(timestamp)` -- but your version should have reasonable performance as well with such an index.

Answer (score 0):

*By using `UNION` you want to add new data set except already intersecting part. The data set with the interval `datetime >= timestamp'2015-12-31 14:30:00'` already contains the data set returning from the interval `datetime >= timestamp'2015-12-31 20:30:00'`. So no need to use a `UNION` for your case, using as the below query is enough :*

```
select * 
  from table1
 where datetime >= timestamp'2015-12-31 14:30:00'
```